# How can I establish a relationship a Model class with another model class of folder in laravel eloquent??

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4, eloquent

Folder Structure:

```
app
|-Admin.php
|-Admin
     |
     |-Product.php





    Admin.php
    --------------------------------------------------------
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

    class Admin extends Authenticatable
    {
        public function erp()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Admin\Product::class);
        }
    }
    -----------------------------------------------------------



    Product.php
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    namespace App\Admin;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Product extends Model
    {

        protected $primaryKey = 'productcode';
        public $incrementing = false;

        public function updatedBy()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class);
        }
    }

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

But got an error Class 'Admin::class' not found
any solution??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use correct namespaces:

Admin model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use App\Admin\Product;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    public function erp()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Product model:

```
namespace App\Admin;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Admin;

class Product extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'productcode';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function updatedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Admin::class);
    }
}
```

Or add namespace of a model as string, for example `App\Admin`

Answer (score 3):

Please see your name space

```
Product.php
-----------------------------------------------------------
namespace App\Admin;
```

So when you call `Admin::class` it mean `App\Admin\Admin::class`
So please change your relation like this.

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $primaryKey = 'productcode';
    public $incrementing = false;

    public function updatedBy()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
    }
}
```